# Can't connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

When I run this `sudo service mysql`, it works just fine, but when I run this `mysql -u root`, I have an error message :

Access denied to user: 'root'@'@localhost'

How can I fix it ? Do I need to check something in /etc/mysql/my.cnf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing -p - that should prompt you for a password.